# Concise IPA dictionary

Tags: english, ipa, resource-request, dictionary

For decades I have used "A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English" by Kenyon and Knott as a concise and accessible tool in learning the IPA. The fact that it's still in print must mean that people still find it useful, but I'm looking  for a more recent publication which has about the same scope and purpose and surely has some changes in symbols, stress, etc.

Comment: BTW, [Kenyon and Knott is online](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater) now.

Comment: I'd recommend the following three dictionaries, The Routledge Dictionary of Pronunciation for Current English (2nd ed. 2017), the Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary (18th ed., 2011) - also available as an iPhone/iPad app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/english-pronouncing-dictionary/id1203628859, and the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary (Wells 2008, 3rd ed.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want newer, the  Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary current edition dates from 2011. You could even line the two up to see how they differ in their representation of US English.